# Capacitor charging a battery

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries

I can't comment to ask for circuit clarification on some of the other questions addressing this, insufficient reputation, so I am asking as a new question.  Looking at answers to the other questions a capacitor can be used to charge a battery if it acquires a voltage higher than the battery.  Would it be correct to say you all that is needed to charge is a capacitor that will accept a voltage higher than the battery and a diode to prevent the battery charging the capacitor?  A charge regulator so as not to overcharge the battery should also be in the circuit.  What components would be required for a novice in electronics?

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you mean by "charge a battery." A capacitor certainly can supply a certain amount of energy and, given a certain amount of energy, you can put some of it (but never all) into a battery. But, if you are talking about bringing an "empty" battery back up to "full" charge, using only a capacitor as the power supply, then that is unlikely to be a practical solution to any real problem. The main issue is _energy density._ A capacitor capable of storing enough energy to fully recharge any given battery would be hundreds or thousands of times bigger than the battery.

Comment: If you refer to previous questions of yours, you should provide links to them. Also you should edit your old question to improve it rather than open a new one to ask the same question.

Comment: Also this question (if you can clarify it better) will probably get better answers on [Electrical Engineering Stackexchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).